# Return specific column case when

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

### The goal

Return specific column if the product is an offer and has the lowest price.

### The problem

I'm creating an application to products price comparison. I'm already getting the products list and the lowest price of a specific product. But, in a day the product can be set to be an offer and have the lowest price of all other products. When that happens, I must to identify to the user such information — with a flag or something like this.

I'm thinking to do this behavior using the query itself — but I do not know, sometimes it seems that this practice is inconsistent because if the product is not on sale, do not know how I'll handle this in C# that will be waiting for the `productState` column. I need suggestions (and, of course, the syntax, because I don't know [again]).

### Details

I'm using C#.NET + MVC 4 + MySQL + Entity Framework 5 + Stored Procedure + Razor Engine.

The follow fragment returns me the lowest price of a product list to comparison:

```
Min(Case When marketProducts.ProductPromotionalPrice = 0
    Then 
       marketProducts.ProductOriginalPrice 
    Else
       Least(
        marketProducts.ProductPromotionalPrice,
        marketProducts.ProductOriginalPrice
       )End) As minProductPrice,
```

But, I want to do something like this (of course — the syntax is wrong, but "works" to illustrate):

```
Min(Case When marketProducts.ProductPromotionalPrice = 0
    Then 
       marketProducts.ProductOriginalPrice 
    Else
       marketProducts.ProductState = 1 As productState, /* 
                                                           This is a normal
                                                           column.
                                                           1 means that 
                                                           the product is on 
                                                           offer.
                                                        */
       Least(
        marketProducts.ProductPromotionalPrice,
        marketProducts.ProductOriginalPrice
       )End) As minProductPrice,
```

The full query:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getProductsList`(IN `categoryId` INT, IN `productState` INT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    Select product.Id As productId,
        product.Name As productName,
        Min(Case When marketProducts.ProductPromotionalPrice = 0
            Then marketProducts.ProductOriginalPrice Else
            Least(marketProducts.ProductPromotionalPrice, marketProducts.ProductOriginalPrice)
            End) As minProductPrice,
            measure.Name As measureName,
            measure.Abbreviation As measureAbbreviation,
            productsImages.ProductImageThumbnail As thumbnailUrl,
            product.InMarketsQuantity as numberOfMarketsThatHaveThisProduct
    From bm_market_products as marketProducts
    Join bm_products As product On marketProducts.ProductId = product.Id
    Join bm_categories As category On product.CategoryId = category.Id
    Join bm_measures As measure On product.MeasureId = measure.Id
    Join bm_products_images As productsImages On product.Id = productsImages.ProductId
    WHERE (productState Is Null Or marketProducts.ProductState = productState)
    And (categoryId Is Null Or category.Id = categoryId)
    Group By marketProducts.ProductId;
END
```

This procedure returns me the following:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your syntax is wrong is you are stuffing two columns in the space of one, sometimes. The solution is to always have both columns as shown below:

```
Select product.Id As productId,
    product.Name As productName,
    Min(Case When marketProducts.ProductPromotionalPrice = 0
        Then marketProducts.ProductOriginalPrice Else
        Least(marketProducts.ProductPromotionalPrice, marketProducts.ProductOriginalPrice)
        End) As minProductPrice,
    Min(Case When marketProducts.ProductPromotionalPrice = 0
            and marketProducts.ProductPromotionalPrice < marketProducts.ProductOriginalPrice
        Then 0 Else 1
        End) As productState,
        measure.Name As measureName,
        measure.Abbreviation As measureAbbreviation,
        productsImages.ProductImageThumbnail As thumbnailUrl,
        product.InMarketsQuantity as numberOfMarketsThatHaveThisProduct
From bm_market_products as marketProducts
Join bm_products As product On marketProducts.ProductId = product.Id
Join bm_categories As category On product.CategoryId = category.Id
Join bm_measures As measure On product.MeasureId = measure.Id
Join bm_products_images As productsImages On product.Id = productsImages.ProductId
WHERE (productState Is Null Or marketProducts.ProductState = productState)
And (categoryId Is Null Or category.Id = categoryId)
Group By marketProducts.ProductId;
```